# sort and output records with SAS and R

Tags: r, sas

I have the following data set

```
PatientName BVAID   Rank    TreatmentCode   TreatmentID DoseID  
Tim Stuart  BVA-027 3   OP_TBC            1             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-041 4   OP_TBC            1             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-021 7   OP_TBC            1             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-048 10  OP_TBC            1             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-020 14  OP_TBC            1             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-024 15  OP_TBC            1             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-001 16  OP_TBC            1             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-013 27  OP_TBC            1             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-018 28  OP_TBC            1             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-051 29  OP_TBC            1             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-027 3   OP_TC             2             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-041 4   OP_TC             2             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-048 10  OP_TC             2             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-020 14  OP_TC             2             1    
Tim Stuart  BVA-001 16  OP_TC             2             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-002 17  OP_TC             2             1    
Tim Stuart  BVA-019 18  OP_TC             2             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-044 22  OP_TC             2             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-025 23  OP_TC             2             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-016 26  OP_TC             2             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-013 27  OP_TC             2             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-001 16  OP_SICO           3             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-002 17  OP_SICO           3             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-013 27  OP_SICO           3             1
```

I need to output the records with the smallest `rank` in each `TreatmentID` group however if the record was outputted in the previous `TreatmentID` group I need to select the next smallest `rank` and output the record for the `TreamtmentID` group - I only need one record per `TreatmentID` group.
This needs to be a scalable solution that I can automate.
My output file will only have tree unique records i.e. one per each group and each records is unique in `BVAID` and will have the smallest rank in that group.

```
PatientName BVAID   Rank    TreatmentCode   TreatmentID DoseID  
Tim Stuart  BVA-027 3   OP_TBC            1             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-041 4   OP_TC             2             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-001 16  OP_SICO           3             1
```

which program can handle this better SAS or R

Comment: When you say scalable, how large a dataset do you believe your solution would need to consider?

Comment: What does "if the record was outputted in the previous TreatmentID" mean? No duplicate BVAIDs? or No duplicate TreatmentCodes?

Answer (score 13):

Compact, scalable and readable R solution :

```
require(data.table)
DT = as.data.table(dat)   # dat input from Brian's answer
r = 0
DT[,{r<<-min(Rank[Rank>r]); .SD[Rank==r]}, by=TreatmentID]

     TreatmentID PatientName   BVAID Rank TreatmentCode DoseID
[1,]           1  Tim Stuart BVA-027    3        OP_TBC      1
[2,]           2  Tim Stuart BVA-041    4         OP_TC      1
[3,]           3  Tim Stuart BVA-001   16       OP_SICO      1
```

Comment: Ding ding ding! I think we have a winner!

Comment: Now, can you extend it so that: (a) it will work even if Treatment ID is not always in ascending order within Patient (e.g. by adding something like `key=c("PatientName", "TreatmentID"` in the call to `as.data.table`); and (b) it will work for an actual data set with more than one Patient? That second piece seems a bit more complicated -- I've got some ideas, and will try them out in a bit, if you haven't already posted something more elegant by then ;)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien `by=` already does retain the order of the groups as they first appear in `DT` so it already does (a) and (b). I linked here from an issue I just raised [#1880](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1880) to discuss a change to make that clearer. Interested in your view.

Comment: Hi Matt. Thanks for pointing me to that cool proposal and interesting discussion of how `by=` et al. work. First, a caveat: I rarely work with data for which the speedup would be a significant win. That said, it should definitely be made available to those who do need it (and I would likely use that option, since it seems cleaner to me to work with data that appear in properly sorted order).

Comment: I might be inclined to permanently leave `by` with its current behavior, while adding a switch argument (`keeporder=` or something like that, with default value `TRUE`). Those few users who need the speedup could then set `keeporder=FALSE` to get the more streamlined behavior of `by`.

Comment: I tend to think most users will find the reordering produced by your proposed solution jarring, in part because, if they're anything like me, they glance at the first few rows of original and resultant `data.table`s as a basic sanity check, for reassurance that their `[.data.table` call did what they wanted it to. That's maybe not optimal or correct user behavior, but I think it is how us humans actually behave. Facilitating that sort of checking, by default, might also be seen as in keeping with R's status a language well suited for exploratory analyses.

Comment: Those are my thoughts, but I tend to defer to you as the much better and more experienced developer.

Comment: Many thanks @JoshO'Brien. Will leave it open for a long time. Main thing now is to get `keyby=` working at proper speed and we'll see how things settle after that then.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an R solution. I'd be really interested to know if there's a method that's much more compact than this.

```
library(plyr)

df <- df[order(df$PatientName, df$TreatmentID),]

ddply(df, .(PatientName), function(DF) {
    # For each Treatment, find the value of Rank to be kept    
    splitRanks <- split(DF$Rank, DF$TreatmentID)
    minRanks <- Reduce(f = function(X, Y) min(Y[Y>min(X)]), 
                       x = splitRanks[-1], 
                       init = min(splitRanks[[1]]), accumulate = TRUE)
    # For each Treatment, extract row w/ Rank determined by the calculation above
    splitDF <- split(DF, DF$TreatmentID)
    rows <- mapply(FUN = function(X, Y) X[X$Rank==Y,], splitDF, minRanks, 
                   SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
    # Bind the extracted rows back together in a data frame
    do.call("rbind", rows)
})

#   PatientName   BVAID Rank TreatmentCode TreatmentID DoseID
# 1  Tim Stuart BVA-027    3        OP_TBC           1      1
# 2  Tim Stuart BVA-041    4         OP_TC           2      1
# 3  Tim Stuart BVA-001   16       OP_SICO           3      1
```

Comment: Nice use of `Reduce` to step through the `TreatmentID`s.

Answer (score 5):

My SAS solution.  All steps are scalable:

```
data test;
  input  PatientName $ 1-10
         BVAID $ 
         Rank    
         TreatmentCode $  
         TreatmentID 
         DoseID 
        ;
datalines;
Tim Stuart  BVA-027 3   OP_TBC            1             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-041 4   OP_TBC            1             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-021 7   OP_TBC            1             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-048 10  OP_TBC            1             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-020 14  OP_TBC            1             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-024 15  OP_TBC            1             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-001 16  OP_TBC            1             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-013 27  OP_TBC            1             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-018 28  OP_TBC            1             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-051 29  OP_TBC            1             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-027 3   OP_TC             2             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-041 4   OP_TC             2             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-048 10  OP_TC             2             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-020 14  OP_TC             2             1    
Tim Stuart  BVA-001 16  OP_TC             2             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-002 17  OP_TC             2             1    
Tim Stuart  BVA-019 18  OP_TC             2             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-044 22  OP_TC             2             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-025 23  OP_TC             2             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-016 26  OP_TC             2             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-013 27  OP_TC             2             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-001 16  OP_SICO           3             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-002 17  OP_SICO           3             1  
Tim Stuart  BVA-013 27  OP_SICO           3             1  
;
run;

proc sort data=test;
  by treatmentid;
run;

data test2;
  set test;
  by treatmentid;
  retain smallest;

  **
  ** CREATE AN EMPTY HASH TABLE THAT WE CAN STORE A LIST OF 
  ** RANKS IN THAT HAVE ALREADY BEEN USED. DONE THIS WAY FOR
  ** SCALABILITY.
  *;
  if _n_ eq 1 then do;
    declare hash ht();
    ht.definekey ('rank');
    ht.definedone();
  end;

  if first.treatmentid then do;
    smallest = .;
  end;

  **
  ** IF THE CURRENT RANK HAS NOT ALREADY BEEN USED THEN 
  ** EVALUATE IT TO SEE IF ITS THE SMALLEST VALUE.
  *;
  if ht.find() ne 0 then do;
    smallest = min(smallest,rank);
  end;

  **
  ** SAVE THE SMALLEST UNUSED RANK BACK TO THE RANK VALUE.
  ** THEN ADD IT TO THE HASH TABLE AND FINALLY OUTPUT THE
  ** OBSERVATION.
  *;
  if last.treatmentid then do;
    rank = smallest;
    ht.add();    
    output;
  end;

  drop smallest;
run;
```

Does SAS win? jk!  ;-)

Comment: Yes hash is a very elegant solution. Thanks Rob I'll look up hash objects didn't know they can be so flexibile

Comment: Appreciate the example of a Hash object...but did you account for "if the record was outputted in the previous TreatmentID group I need to select the next smallest rank". Not sure if BVAID or TreatmentCode var should not be duplicated...example does not duplicate BVAID var

Comment: Good questions - I'm not sure either!  If the other vars need to be retained than it shouldn't be difficult to modify the above.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another `R` solution.  What makes this a harder problem than most is that it can not be treated as a split-apply-combine problem since the row to be selected depends not only on all rows with a given `TreatmentID`, but also the result of what was determined by the previous (assuming that means the next smallest) `TreatmentID`.

First, the data in a pasteable form (in case anyone else wants to take a crack at it):

```
dat <-
structure(list(PatientName = c("Tim Stuart", "Tim Stuart", "Tim Stuart", 
"Tim Stuart", "Tim Stuart", "Tim Stuart", "Tim Stuart", "Tim Stuart", 
"Tim Stuart", "Tim Stuart", "Tim Stuart", "Tim Stuart", "Tim Stuart", 
"Tim Stuart", "Tim Stuart", "Tim Stuart", "Tim Stuart", "Tim Stuart", 
"Tim Stuart", "Tim Stuart", "Tim Stuart", "Tim Stuart", "Tim Stuart", 
"Tim Stuart"), BVAID = c("BVA-027", "BVA-041", "BVA-021", "BVA-048", 
"BVA-020", "BVA-024", "BVA-001", "BVA-013", "BVA-018", "BVA-051", 
"BVA-027", "BVA-041", "BVA-048", "BVA-020", "BVA-001", "BVA-002", 
"BVA-019", "BVA-044", "BVA-025", "BVA-016", "BVA-013", "BVA-001", 
"BVA-002", "BVA-013"), Rank = c(3L, 4L, 7L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
27L, 28L, 29L, 3L, 4L, 10L, 14L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 22L, 23L, 26L, 
27L, 16L, 17L, 27L), TreatmentCode = c("OP_TBC", "OP_TBC", "OP_TBC", 
"OP_TBC", "OP_TBC", "OP_TBC", "OP_TBC", "OP_TBC", "OP_TBC", "OP_TBC", 
"OP_TC", "OP_TC", "OP_TC", "OP_TC", "OP_TC", "OP_TC", "OP_TC", 
"OP_TC", "OP_TC", "OP_TC", "OP_TC", "OP_SICO", "OP_SICO", "OP_SICO"
), TreatmentID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), DoseID = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("PatientName", "BVAID", 
"Rank", "TreatmentCode", "TreatmentID", "DoseID"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

Now my solution

```
matches <- dat[0,]
TreatmentIDs <- sort(unique(dat$TreatmentID))
for (TreatmentIDidx in seq_along(TreatmentIDs)) {
    TreatmentID <- TreatmentIDs[TreatmentIDidx]
    treat.flg <- dat$TreatmentID == TreatmentID
    match <- dat[treat.flg &
                 dat$Rank == min(setdiff(dat$Rank[treat.flg],
                                         matches$Rank[matches$TreatmentID==
                                                      TreatmentIDs[TreatmentIDidx-1]])),]
    matches <- rbind(matches, match)
}
```

which gives the desired result:

```
> matches
   PatientName   BVAID Rank TreatmentCode TreatmentID DoseID
1   Tim Stuart BVA-027    3        OP_TBC           1      1
12  Tim Stuart BVA-041    4         OP_TC           2      1
22  Tim Stuart BVA-001   16       OP_SICO           3      1
```

My `SAS` is rusty, and I don't have a copy to try things with right now, so I'll leave it to someone else to make a `SAS` solution to compare with.

Comment: Your description of why this is a harder-than-usual problem is spot on. Thanks too for including the cut-and-paste ready data in your answer!

Comment: Thanks Brian - nice solution in R I'll experiment with different size data sets I wander how many records can R handle

Answer (score 2):

my sas solution.

assume that you have data set (test) and sort it like what you have done here (by patientname, treatmentid then rank). This code fits in multiple patientnames situation and assume that these steps are performed for every one of patientname (delete all patientname related if you don't want this level )

```
%macro m1();
%begin: proc append base=new data=test(firstobs=1 obs=1);

data _null_;
set test(firstobs=1 obs=1);
call symput('r', rank);
call symput('id',Treatmentid);
call symput('name',patientname);

data test;
set test;
if (rank=&r or Treatmentid=&id) and patientname=symget('name') then delete;

%let dsid=%sysfunc(open(test));
%let nobs=%sysfunc(attrn(&dsid,nobs)); 
%let rc=%sysfunc(close(&dsid));

%if &nobs^=0 %then %goto begin;
%mend;

%m1(); run;
```

Comment: Nice Macro Robbie it's fast I'm going to test which one is faster your macro or hash object. Thanks

Comment: @Makoto You didn't give more detail about your data set, like whether you need to deal with multiple patientnames. Depending on the actual feature of data set, code could be more efficient.